# HAProxy didn't start as service

Tags: centos, haproxy

Did need to configurate and start HAproxy from User without SUDO rights.
in general it turned out to be done.

```
/data/haproxy/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

stdout:

```
[WARNING] 198/141606 (119143) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for frontend 'https-in' as it requires HTTP mode.
[WARNING] 198/141606 (119143) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for backend 'https-servers-basic' as it requires HTTP mode.
[WARNING] 198/141606 (119143) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for backend 'https-servers-redirect' as it requires HTTP mode.
[WARNING] 198/141606 (119143) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for backend 'https-servers-service' as it requires HTTP mode.
```

process did start OK:

```
[test@ser-app-0001 haproxy]$ ps aux | grep haproxy
test   5109  0.3  0.0  49040  5224 ?        Ss   15:37   0:00 /data/haproxy/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

After I did want to make service.
Create ha.service file in /etc/systemd/system

```
[Unit]
Description=ha.service
[Service]
Type=simple
User=test
WorkingDirectory=/data/haproxy/
ExecStart=/data/haproxy/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
SyslogIdentifier=ha.service-log
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

after:

```
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl start ha.service && systemctl status ha.service
```

in result Service did start and 1-2 second ago did down:

```
Jul 18 15:41:26 ser-app-0001 systemd[1]: ha.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 18 15:41:26 ser-app-0001 systemd[1]: Started ha.service.
Jul 18 15:41:26 ser-app-0001 systemd[1]: Starting ha.service...
Jul 18 15:41:26 ser-app-0001 ha.service-log[5871]: [WARNING] 198/154126 (5871) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for frontend 'https-in' as it requires HTTP mode.
Jul 18 15:41:26 ser-app-0001 ha.service-log[5871]: [WARNING] 198/154126 (5871) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for backend 'https-servers-basic' as it requires HTTP mode.
Jul 18 15:41:26 ser-app-0001 ha.service-log[5871]: [WARNING] 198/154126 (5871) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for backend 'https-servers-redirect' as it requires HTTP mode.
Jul 18 15:41:26 ser-app-0001 ha.service-log[5871]: [WARNING] 198/154126 (5871) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for backend 'https-servers-service' as it requires HTTP mode.
Jul 18 15:41:26 ser-app-0001 systemd[1]: ha.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 18 15:41:26 ser-app-0001 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for ha.service
Jul 18 15:41:26 ser-app-0001 systemd[1]: Failed to start ha.service.
Jul 18 15:41:26 ser-app-0001 systemd[1]: Unit ha.service entered failed state.
Jul 18 15:41:26 ser-app-0001 systemd[1]: ha.service failed.
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: Kill off all instances manually first and then try a start through systemctl

Comment: Absent stoped|working services and processes using haproxy.

Comment: Please share the haproxy.cfg

Comment: What version of haproxy? Earlier versions came with a `haproxy-systemd-wrapper`, needed to make haproxy compliant with systemd.